# I have a memory allocation error with every AI-based app on my pc

Tags: memory-management

Every time I use AI app such as Stable Diffusion, Language models or Voice changer etc. The following error occurs:
`Unrecognized CachingAllocator option: 1024`

I have tried reinstalling apps, changing their configs but it doesn's help at all. Also I have newest nvidia drivers.

I have Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 with 12Gb VRAM. My platform is windows. All programmes work on python

Comment: What GPU do you have and what amount of VRAM does it have? What platform are you running your AI software on and does it have a supported CUDA version installed?

Comment: I have Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 with 12Gb VRAM. My platform is windows if I understood this correctly. All programmes work on python, and I haven't seen any requests to directly install cuda on the PC in the instructions for installing these apps

Comment: Please add that additional information to the question, as it's useful for answering it. CUDA should have been installed with the Nvidia driver. Is you version of Python supported by the software you're attempting to run?

Comment: It uses build-in python